# Node.js integration with MS Exchange EWS

Tags: node.js, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ntlm

I am attempting to use Node.js to call the SOAP Exchange EWS services. I have created a simple http client like so:

```javascript
var https = require('https');

var username = 'user';
var password = 'password';
var auth = 'NTLM ' + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString('base64');

var options = {
    host : 'exchangehost',
    port : 443,
    method : 'post',
    path : '/Exchange.asmx',
    headers : { Authorization : auth }
};

var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
    console.log('Status: ' + response.statusCode);
};

request.write('<soapenv:Envelope  ...></soapenv:Envelope>');
request.end();
```

I receive a status code 401, I suspect because I am not doing the three steps involved for NTLM authentication (http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html). Does anyone know of a Node.js module for communicating with Exchange EWS directly or for authenticating using NTLM, or am I going to need to implement that protocol for Node.js myself? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. We decided to go with a Kerberos authentication instead in part because of the issues we were having here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [`node-ews`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ews) successfully to communicate with EWS.

`node-ews` uses `httpntlm` internally for NTLM authentication.

Personally, I think **node-ews** is your best bet, since its pretty much already implemented everything you need to interact with EWS.

Comment: Hi Aaron, have you by any chance managed to use the GetRoom function? I'm trying to get the calendars for my works room to see which are available

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup I have not, however, there are a few steps you  must get right. 1) have a well formated JSON object for the request see [issue#27](https://github.com/nmarus/node-ews/issues/27) at `node-ews` project page. 2) make sure the parameters you are using are valid (like correct email address). Feel free to [create an issue](https://github.com/nmarus/node-ews/issues/new) and I will try to help as much as I can.

Comment: Thank you :-)  Im a bit confused about the name EWS are using, Is it correct that its Appointments/meeting for a Room(by email or name) i need to find, and not a Calender?
I will make a case trying to explain what I have done and where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the httpntlm module? https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm

Comment: This looks promising and simple. I'm not trying to do this anymore but if someone can verify that it works I'll mark it as accepted since this appears to be a more general purpose NTLM connector.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ews-javascript-api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api) npm module, it has all the features you are looking at + very simple ntlm authentication using [ews-javascript-api-auth](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api-auth) module. NTLMv2 is also supported.

I added this as answer as it would provide complete answer to question title (integration). These are github links, question is little generic so samples provided at github readme should work.

[disclaimer - I am the author]

Answer (score -1):

I've found this one Node.js module that supports communicating with Exchange 2010, however I'm still trying to figure out how to use it personally, the documentation is light.
https://npmjs.org/package/exchanger

Comment: Thanks, looking for more of a direct approach without the module. I'll check that out though and see if the module works as well.

Comment: I tryed to use `exchanger` but at the moment there is an error with `node-expat` that prevented me from further testing. `Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/node_expat.node'`